# Friend function cannot access private members

Tags: c++, friend-function

When reading *C++ Primer* I encountered the following snippet (I've omitted code that I think is irrelevant):

```cpp
class Message {
  friend class Folder;

 public:
  // ...

 private:
  std::string contents;
  std::set<Folder*> folders;
  // ...
};

// ...
void swap(Message& lhs, Message& rhs) {
  using std::swap;
  for (auto f : lhs.folders) { f->remMsg(&lhs); }
  // class Folder is undefined by book
  // ...
}
// ...
```

*C++ Primer* gives a task to implement `class Folder`. So I add more code::

```cpp
class Folder;   // my code

class Message {
  friend void swap(Message&, Message&);  // my code
  friend class Folder;

 public:
  // ...

 private:
  std::string contents;
  std::set<Folder*> folders;
  // ...
};

void swap(Message&, Message&);  // my code

// I added the whole class
class Folder {
  friend void swap(Folder&, Folder&);
  friend class Message;

 public:
  // ...

 private:
  // ...
  void addMsg(Message* m) { msgs.insert(m); }
  void remMsg(Message* m) { msgs.erase(m); }
};

void swap(Folder&, Folder&);    // my code
```

**In `file.cpp`**

```
void swap(Message& lhs, Message& rhs) {
  using std::swap;
  for (auto f : lhs.folders) { f->remMsg(&lhs); }
  // In vs2019 
  // Error (active) E0265   function "Folder::remMsg" is inaccessible
  // ...
}
```

As you can see, I can't use the method `Folder::remMsg()`.

Then I try to figure out how friend function works.

```cpp
struct B;  // This is [line 1]

struct A {
  friend void swap(A&, A&);

 private:
  int n;
  std::vector<B*> Bs;
};

void swap(A& lhs, A& rhs) {
  for (auto f : lhs.Bs) { f->n; }
  // f->n is still inaccessible
  // If I delete line 1, the code can be compiled successfully
  // same with class Folder
  // ...
}

struct B {
  friend struct A;

 private:
  int n;
  A C;
};
```

I don't understand why does this happen.

<sub>(I declare `class Message` and `class Folder` friend class with each other because I want symmetric `swap` to use copy-swap)</sub>

Comment: Declaring `Folder` as a `friend` of `Message` means that MEMBER FUNCTIONS of `Folder` can call `private` member function of `Message`.   The function `swap()` is not a member or `friend` of `Message` so cannot access private members of `Message`.

Comment: `f->n` tries to access a private member of `B`. Friendship is not transitive; `swap` being a friend of `A` and `A` being a friend of `B` does not imply that `swap` is a friend of `B`. (That the `B` instance happens to be accessed "through" an instance of `A` doesn't matter; accessibility doesn't "transfer".)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`void swap(Message& lhs, Message& rhs)` is a friend of `Message`, but you try to access private members of `Folder`. Your last code has the same issue: `friend void swap(A&, A&);` is a friend of `A` but you try to access private members of `B`. `friend` is not transitive. Just because `A` is friend of `B` and `swap` is a friend of `A` does not mean `swap` is a friend of `B`.

If you want `void swap(A&,A&)` grant access to private member of `B` then make it a friend of `B`:

```
#include <vector>

struct B;

struct A {
  friend void swap(A&, A&);

 private:
  int n;
  std::vector<B*> Bs;
};

struct B {
  friend void swap(A&,A&);

 private:
  int n;
  A C;
};

void swap(A& lhs, A& rhs) {
  for (auto f : lhs.Bs) { f->n; }
                // ^^ access private member of A
                        //^^ access private member of B
}
```

Comment: This sentence that friend is not transitive is crucial. Thank you.